# Problems with unlinking more than one picture at a time

Tags: php

I have a problem with unlinking more than one picture at the time. I am deleting from a folder where the name of the picture(s) is recived from a $_POST "command". When I `print_r("The $_POST here");` it shows up like this (with more that one picture): `FolderName/picture1.jpgFoldername/picture2.jpg`. Is this why it does not work to delete more than one picture at the time?

I am using this code to delete the picture(s), where the picture(s) name(s) is recived from a MySQL table:

```
if ($_POST["examplePost"]) {
        // DELETE PICTURE(s)
$maal = $row_exampleRow['picture'];

if (file_exists($maal)) {
    unlink($maal);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to pass only one path to the unlink function. So split your string and loop over the result.

Comment: Is picture name coming from a multi-entry `<input type="file">` tag of some sort?  Basically more context would be nice.  What is `'examplePost'` on the client?  What is `$row_exampleRow` and where is it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I will just copy the whole code :)  :

```
<?php
require_once('Connections/GeoPlassPosisjon_2.php');
require_once("uregistrerte_bilete.php");
?>
<?php
// Namn på knapp
if (isset($_POST["slettBileteUR"])) {
    // Namn på sjekkboks
  $checkbox = $_POST["cURBileteNamn"];
    $countCheck = count($_POST["cURBileteNamn"]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $countCheck; $i++) {
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];

    $sql2 = "SELECT l_o_bid, bilete_namn FROM ur_lasta_opp_bileter WHERE l_o_bid = '$del_id'";
    $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    $count2 = mysql_fetch_row($res2);
    unset($count2[0]);
    foreach($count2 as $bilete_namnUR);

        // SLETTE BILETE
    // PHP kode for å slette bilete frå server mappa
// Visst $bilete_namnUR (bilete) eksistere --> slett $bilete_namnUR (bilete)
if (file_exists($bilete_namnUR)) {
    unlink($bilete_namnUR);
}

        $sql = "DELETE from ur_lasta_opp_bileter WHERE l_o_bid = $del_id";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error('Kan desverre ikkje koble til databasen.'));
}

if ($res) {
    header ("location: uregistrerte_bilete.php");
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'errorUrBilSlettJS();', '</script>';
  }
}   

?>
```

Thank you all for the help I recived ! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

unlink() supports for one file only.

**There are two approaches you might want to consider.**

**Approach 1**
Sending them in form input[]

```
<form method='post'>
    <input name='filename[]'><BR/>
    <input name='filename[]'><BR/>
    <input name='filename[]'><BR/>
    <input name='filename[]'><BR/>
    <input name='filename[]'><BR/>
    <input name='filename[]'><BR/>
    <input type=submit>
</forM>
```

Then you might get the POST array in the php script.

> ```
>    array (size=1)
>   'filename' => 
>     array (size=6)
>       0 => string 'aw' (length=2)
>       1 => string 'awf' (length=3)
>       2 => string 'fawf' (length=4)
>       3 => string '' (length=0)
>       4 => string '' (length=0)
>       5 => string '' (length=0)
> ```

**Approach 2**
You might need to parse the incoming string.
Like explode(',' , $_POST['filenames']) , if they are comma separated.

```
<form method='post'>
    <input name='filenames'>
    <input type=submit>
</forM>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :D I didn't see your comment before now; but I also figured out an answer to this. I will post it. :)

Comment: Glad it helped. :) By the way, you might also want to consider not using mysql_ functions, you can google it to see more.